# My plugin has templates directory , none of them is executing any of the wp functions. All are throwing fatal error : call to undefined function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and creating a plugin, an error log has been created automatically in my plugins templates folder which listed so many errors saying -

> [22-Dec-2015 07:57:25 Etc/GMT] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined
>   function wp_redirect() in
>   /home/techgwpj/public_html/www.hostrecyclers.com/WP/doctor/wp-content/plugins/tg-doctorin/templates/user-activation.php
>   on line 12.

When I was doing the same thing from my `themes/templates` folder this was working fine, but as soon as i placed the same code into my plugins/templates folder it stopped working and a blank page appeared and all the wp functions became undefined 
i.e. `wp_redirect, get_header(), get_footer()` etc

Comment: How are you calling on this template?

Comment: get_header(); inside plugins/tg-doctorin/templates/user-activation.php file...But it is throwing Fatal error: call to undefined function get_header()

Comment: infact every wp function is undefined here in this folder files.

Comment: No I mean how are you calling the whole user-activation.php file?

Comment: add_filter('page_template', 'catch_mypath');
function catch_mypath($page_template)
{
    if (is_page('user')) {
        $page_template = DOC_URL. '/templates/my_profile.php';
    }
  if (is_page('user-activation')) {
        $page_template = DOC_URL. '/templates/user-activation.php';
    }
 if (is_page('user-edit')) {
        $page_template = DOC_URL. '/templates/edit-profile.php';
    }
    return $page_template;
}

Comment: This code exists in my main file of plugin directory

Comment: hey, y m i unable to see your suggession, its showing me the message that i need atleast 2k reputation to see your suggession.. what should i do? is there any other means u can suggest me?